# How to pass an input as a string to SQL plus from shell script

Tags: sql, linux, dynamic, parameters

Im getting the status value from get_status. The value which I get will be a number or a character. I tried to pass this dynamically to SQLPlus. It executes fine, if I pass 1 as a value for stat, if I pass the char P as a value for stat, it throws an error as INVALID IDENTIFER.
Can someone please help on this

My code is:
get_status()
{
returns the value as P or 1
}
stat=$(get_status)
echo 'status is' $stat

if [[ "$stat" == "1" ]]
then
 tbl_name=l_s_queue
elif [[ "$stat" == "P" ]]
then
 tbl_name=s_queue
stat="'$stat'"

fi;

File_name=events.csv
sqlplus -S -l $username@$dbname/$password @pe.sql $File_name $tbl_name $stat

Comment: How is the parameter `&3` used in the script `pe.sql`?

Comment: Why have you reverted the [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58273580/2) made by @Serg? With that changes your code was readable, unlike to the current question state.